# RxJs switchMap with angular HttpClient

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-httpclient, switchmap

I have a use case whenever a new request is triggered, any http requests that are already in flight should be cancelled / ignored.

***For eg***:

> - A request (say #2) comes in while the request #1 takes too long to respond / slow network connectivity.
> - In this case #2 gets a very quick response from server then at any point even if the #1 comes back with a response the HTTP response
>     observable should be ignored.
> - The problem i face is, first the component displays response values from request #2 and gets updated again when req #1 completes (this should not happen).

I figured that switchMap cancels obervables / maintains the order in which the observable values are emitted.

**excerpt from my service.ts**

```js
Obervable.of('myServiceUrl')
             .switchMap(url => this.httpRequest(url) )
              .subscribe( response => {
                   // implementation
                   /** Update an observable with the 
                       with latest changes from response. this will be 
                       displayed in a component as async */
                });


private httpRequest(url) {
        return this.httpClient.get('myUrl', { observe: 'response' });
}
```

The above implementation doesn't work. Could some one figure out the correct implementation for this usecase.

Comment: How are you using `httpResponse$`?

Comment: I don't need the httpResponse$ as all the implementation is taken care inside subscribe(). updated the code snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the below code excerpt with which the switchMap implementation was successfull.

```js
class MyClass {
    private domain: string;
    private myServiceUri: subject;
    myData$: Observable<any>;

        constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
            .....
            this.myServiceUri = new Subject();
            this.myServiceUri.switchMap(uri => {
                    return this.http.get(uri , { observe: 'response' })
                            // we have to catch the error else the observable sequence will complete
                            .catch(error => {
                                // handle error scenario
                                return Obervable.empty(); //need this to continue the stream
                            });
                    })
                    .subscribe(response => {
                        this.myData$.next(response);
                    });
        }

        getData(uri: string) {
            this.myServiceUri.next(this.domain + uri); // this will trigger the request     
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is `myData$`? I don't see a observable being created

Answer (score 14):

It seems like you are creating multiple observables. It's unclear from your example, but it seems like you call `Observable.of` each time you want to make the request. This creates a *new* Observable stream each time, so for each subsequent call you get a new stream, and the previous one is not canceled. This is why `.switchMap` is not working.

If you want `.switchMap` to cancel the HTTP requests, you need them to use the *same* observable stream. The source Observable you want to use depends on what exactly is triggering the http requests, but you can manage it yourself using something like `Subject`.

```
const makeRequest$ = new Subject();
const myResponse$ = makeRequest$.pipe(switchMap(() => this.service.getStuff()));
```

You can subscribe to `myResponse$` to get the response. Any time you want to trigger a request, you can do `makeRequest$.next()`.

Comment: well that makes sense. so with the above implementation the makeRequest$ holds the actual http get request i used. am i right ? let me implement and get back.

Comment: `makeRequest$` is just a Subject (Observable) that doesn't really do anything. You just emit to it to cause the observable stream to emit. `myResponse$` will have the http response that you want.

Comment: I am getting error when use above approach i.e. TypeError: `this.myServiceUri.pipe.switchMap` is not a function. Also when I use this vscode shows ` import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';` as unused.

Answer (score 1):

An approach which might seem similar to above answer but implementation is different.

In the below example, you can see that the API/http calls get cancelled if called multiple times. The purpose is to avoid API calls resolving which eventually causes browser to respond slowly.(Ex: Typeahead)

**switchMap** at a time can hold only one observable. Hence, it cancels rest of the API calls.

**switch-map.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'switch-map',
    templateUrl: './switch-map.component.html'
})
export class SwitchMapComponent implements OnInit {
    subject: Subject<string> = new Subject()

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    makeApiCall(): void {
        this.subject.next('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.subject.pipe(switchMap(url => this.http.get(url)))
        .subscribe(data => console.log('API Response: ', data))
        setInterval(() => {
            document.getElementById('btn')?.click()
        }, 10)
    }
}
```

**switch-map.component.html**

```
<button id="btn" (click)="makeApiCall()">Click</button>
```